# How to grep all unique ip address in /var/log/messages and send them to another log file

Tags: grep, rhel, logs, bind

I am in the prosses of decommissioning an old Redhat public BIND server and would like to find all unique IP address that are sending DNS request to this Nameserver. So far this is what I have been able to cobble together, but this command is including more than just the IP of the clients sending the request.

```
egrep -o [0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\} /var/log/messages | sort | uniq -c > dns-ip-client.log
```

How would I go about making this work?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of items do you get that you don't want to see in the output? Maybe you can filter out other stuff before applying your regex? e.g. `grep bind | egrep -o ...`

Comment: I think it would be hard to list only valid IP addresses. I have no experience with BIND but maybe you could expand  your regex with something that BIND always prints when it logs?

Comment: Please provide the log entry structure of this service.

Comment: Don't grep directly all the IPs from the log. First filter only BIND related entries, then `grep` IPs from it.

Comment: Kindly post  the sample logs

Comment: I was able to narrow down my search using this command.

`cat /var/log/messages | grep -o 'client XXX\{1,3\}\.XXX\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | sort -u > dns-client-ip.log`

XXX is the first and second octet.

Comment: This is a sample log from BIND 

Jun 20 11:51:17 mail named[3571]: client 000.000.11.49#55996: view hosted: query: ap.lijit.com IN A +

I replace the first and secound octet for anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting/escaping is tripping you up I think. Single quotes tend to make things easier:

```
grep 'named' /var/log/messages | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Note that `grep -E` == `egrep` but "Direct invocation as either egrep or  fgrep  is  deprecated"